# Aria2 disable P2P BitTorrent?

Tags: aria2

- Is it possible to disable P2P BitTorrent in aria2c?
- If it's not possible in aria2, how could I block P2P with iptables?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-enable-peer-exchange), you can start aria2c with the `--enable-peer-exchange` set to `false` and that's that.

> `--enable-peer-exchange [true|false]`
>
> Enable Peer Exchange extension. If a private flag is set in a torrent, this feature is disabled for that download even if true is
>   given. Default: `true`

---

However, if you want an aria2 version that **does not support** BitTorrent or Metalink, you can built it yourself and just provide `--disable-bittorrent` and `--disable-metalink` to the configure script.

[You can find building instruction on its README](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/README.html#how-to-get-source-code).